# Oath facebook error: “URL blocked: This redirect failed because...“ and cannot get

Tags: node.js, mongodb, facebook, session

I saw all the possible answers online but I just cannot get this to work and don't understand why. First problem I came across is the usual: "URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app's Client OAuth Settings". After a few hours trial and error, trying every possible way (http, https, www, and without) and I managed the app to save the FacebookId in mongoDB (although didn`t prompt me to the Facebook login page), but right after now I have Cannot GET /auth/facebook message.. Now I know I have an issue already in mondoDB because at this point no multiple account can be saved without and email address as username would be NULL and only one allowed, but after wiping the DB I can sign in with Google oath without and issue so, it seems like I have a problem setting up

> Facebook and i just don`t know what im doing wrong. Thank you in advanced!

[facebooksettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISGoQ.png)
[facebooksettings2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN5GY.png)

the site url set to: https://app-secret.herokuapp.com/

```
app.js
...
//use session package with some setup config//
app.use(session({
  secret: 'My little secret.',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
}))

//initalize passport packadge and for also to deal with the session//
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://andras:MYPASSWORD@cluster0.zfr0d.mongodb.net/userDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

//schema in order to have a plugin it has to be a mongoose schema//
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String,
  secret: Array
});

//adding plugins to schema//
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

//configuring passport, serialize=create and deserialize=able to crack open cookie//
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://app-secret.herokuapp.com/auth/google/secrets",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    // console.log(profile);
    User.findOrCreate({
      googleId: profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "https://app-secret.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({
      facebookId: profile.id
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home")
});

app.get("/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ["profile"]
  })
);

app.get("/auth/google/secrets",
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: "/login"
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/secrets');
  });

app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/secrets',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/secrets');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry to spam stackoverflow with my rookie misery. I realised where i went wrong, i thought the facebook API is the one creating me headache and not realising that the **facebook callback in the app.js missing the correct path**.. instead of: "app-secret.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook" **it should be: "app-secret.herokuapp.com/auth/facebook/secrets"**